# У меня есть игровой бот на php для ВКонтакте, такой вопросик у меня

Tags: php

В файле бот bot.php у меня всё. И команды, и переменные. Вообщем то, можно как то сделать так чтобы команды находились в одном файлике, переменные с настройками бота в другом (токены, начальный баланс)? Как я понял нужно делать это через классы, но не очень понял как это реализовать, буду благодарен если поможете)

Comment: Если вам надо сделать это на ООП - да, через классы, если просто вынести что-то в "конфиг" - можно просто перенести эти переменные в другой файл и этот "другой файл" подключить в первом

Comment: Учите PHP. Так вам проще будет помочь

Answer (score 1):

Переменные например хранишь в файле config.php, а команды в bot.php

В начале bot.php просто инклудишь нужные переменные:

```
include 'config.php';
```

И после инклуда просто обращаешься к нужным переменным.
Вместо инклуда можно использовать require

include от require отличается тем, что require требует этот файл. Тоесть, если файл не будет найден - выполняемый скрипт выдаст фатальную ошибку и остановится. Если файл с переменными очень важен, используйте require, так безопаснее

Comment: Могли бы тогда рассказать и поподробнее про include и require, почему стоит использовать то или другое. В его случае require, т.к. файлы необходимы для работы.